# To check if two words are equal to each other?(C)

Tags: c

**Hello.I want to make a simple English-Turkish dictionary. This is my homework.I have to code with C but I don't know C at all.  Why doesn't my following code work?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;

    char word_array[10][20] ={"araba","car","kalem","pencil","derin","deep","mavi","blue","el","hand" };
    //char arama[5] = {'d','e','r','i','n'};
    char search[10] = "araba ";


    for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i=i+2){
        if(word_array[i] == search){
            printf("i found: %s\n",i);
        }
        else{
            printf("The word isnt in the array. %s\n",word_array[i],search);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't. Use `strcmp`. and it won't either because there's a space in the end of `"araba "`

Comment: In C you can neither assign (apart from definitions) or compare a string without using `strcpy` or `strcmp`

Comment: that's right. you cannot compare with "if(word_array[i] == search". try a different data structure and use the string compares as others have said.

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with your code example, to the point where someone might need to rewrite the entire block to give you any real help.

Comment: In `i=i+2` why are you trying to avoid half the strings?

Comment: @WeatherVane Turkish(even position)-English(odd position) dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the code below. It fixed few issues with your code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
        int i;

        char word_array[10][20] ={"araba","car","kalem","pencil","derin","deep","mavi","blue","el","hand" };
        char search[10] = "araba";


        for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
            if(strcmp(word_array[i],search) == 0){
                printf("i found: %s\n",i);
                break;
            }
       }

       if(i>=10) {
            printf("The word %s isnt in the array.\n",search);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `printf("i found: %d\n",i);` (or `printf("i found: %s\n", word_array[i]);` or `printf("i found: %s\n", word_array[i+1]);`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // <-------- Include header containing strcmp()
int main()
{
    int i;

    char word_array[10][20] = { "araba", "car", "kalem", "pencil", "derin", "deep", "mavi", "blue", "el", "hand" };
    //char arama[5] = {'d','e','r','i','n'};
    char search[10] = "araba"; // <-------- Remove space to have the same string.


    for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1){ // <-------- Search each word in array as opposed to each second word.
        if (strcmp(word_array[i], search) == 0){ // <-------- Use proper C-string comparison.
            printf("%i found: %s\n", i, word_array[i]); // <-------- Correct specifier "i" to "%i" and add the actual found word to output for "%s"
        }
        else{
            printf("The word isnt in the array. %s\n", word_array[i], search);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also see: [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: `printf("The word isnt in the array. %s\n", word_array[i], search);` : arguments mismatch. and move to outside of for-loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Depends on what he wants to do with that line(isn't the prettiest that's for sure). However, moving it outside of the loop in it's current form won't do any good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)